# In Visual Studio, how to sort class members/methods in Solution Explorer only?

Tags: visual-studio, solution-explorer

This question is about **Visual Studio**.

Is there any way (or extension) to sort class members and methods alphabetically, but only in the **Solution Explorer** window?
I don't want to change code of a class.